# Sublime parse error default(windows).sublime-keymap:221

Tags: sublimetext2

When i try to start sublime I get the following error;

```
Error trying to parse file: Unexpected charachter, expected a comma or closing 
bracket in c:\Users\Victor\AppData\RoaminSublime Text 2\Packages\User\
Default (Windows).sublime-keymap:221.
```

Sublime isn't starting up, just shows this error. So i don't know how to edit the extra comma or bracket.

I downloaded a fresh copy of sublime but i end up with the same error;sublime doesn't start up  that's my handicap.

I have no idea what to do. How can i fix my issue???

here is the bits and piecies i could copy from my uer.sublime-package file. 
Its realively empty as i installed a fresh copy
    PK,)>nDefault (Linux).sublime-keymap[
    ]

```
PK,)>nDefault (OSX).sublime-keymap[
]

PK,)>nDefault (Windows).sublime-keymap[
]

Preferences.sublime-settings// Settings in here override those in "Default/Preferences.sublime-settings", and
// are overridden in turn by file type specific settings.
{
}
Preferences.sublime-settingsPK
```

Comment: sublime can't start up. so i am unable to look at the user file. When i look at the file user.sublime-package itself there is alot of jiberish, i think cause of the mark up?

Comment: plus i am unable to copy some of its contents

Comment: plus i cant see the exact file sublime-keymap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to open that file through another editor (such as Notepad++). From there you can edit the file. Note that the keymap file is simply JSON. That error just tells you there was some problem parsing it. If you can post the entire file, we can help you fix it.

I wouldn't recommend simply deleting the file since, by the line number giving the error, you have a number of keybindings in place. I doubt you wan't to enter all those again.

Edit:
You shouldn't be looking at the sublime-package file, rather in the `User` directory within `Packages`

Comment: First there isn't any user directory at all and thus i cant find the .sublime-keymap file...i also tried opening the sublime-packagefile with notepad++ but it has alot of jiberish. Ive downloaded reinstalled a fresh copy twice now...still same problem....really confusing

Comment: normally when i use sublime to save anything to the pakages folder id have t have sublime running, navigating to the folder directly through C drive i do not see the pakages/users folder...

Comment: @VictorNjoroge Odd, are you using Sublime Text 2 or Sublime Text 3? In either case, the `.sublime-package` files are just renamed zips. Just rename the file to `User.zip` and extract as you would normally. You should then be able to see the keymap file.

Comment: That was a dumb question on my part. I can see it ST2 from the error message. If you paste the following into Windows Explorer, it won't open a directory? `c:\Users\Victor\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\User\`

Comment: Thanks!! now i was able to see the user directory and keymap file...there was a brace missing...so i added it and it works now..So maybe i phrased my question wrong, i should have asked how to navigate to the user directory. Thanks

Comment: Yup that is odd. As a side note, I would create that User directory in Packages, so you can freely edit things. The sublime-package file should be located at `Sublime Text 2\Pristine Packages`. Extract that to file to `Sublime Text 2\Packages`. It's still odd that you don't have a user directory there.

Comment: My problem was that i was using this path 'C:\Program Files\SublimeText2\Pristine Packages' and this is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It happens due to wrong parsing of default settings.
You can resolve this problem by visiting  c:\Users\Victor\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\User. At this location you will find sublime-settings files.
You need to simply open them in another text editor like notepad and correct their syntax.
For EG: 
  INCORRECT:  auto_complete:false
  CORRECT: "auto_complete":false

Answer (score 0):

This error can be removed very easily because there is only some semicolon or bracket missing from the code from keymap. So, to correct it... just go to **Preferences** in the Sublime Text 3 and then click **Key Bindings**. You will be redirected to the keymap directory and here the errors can be spotted very easily as Sublime will be indicating the error using some color. That's it..Boom...Error is removed!

Answer (score -1):

It seems the file is corrupted.

Delete the file, then reinstall Sublime Text 2. That should work.

Comment: It's clearly a formatting error, it clearly says `expected a comma or closing bracket`. Reinstalling the whole editor just for this is not a healthy suggestion.

Comment: Have you seen the content of its file ? Does "PK,)>nDefault (OSX).sublime-keymap[] PK,)>nDefault (Windows).sublime-keymap[] seems a "healthy" file to you?

Comment: That in no way means the file is corrupt.

Comment: i dont know whether its healthy or not, but what i pasted is what i could copy from sublime-package file, it had alot of other characters that were not copiable (:P new word)

Comment: I didn't see that you tried to paste sublime-package file. When I asked you for the code, I talk about the `Default (Windows).sublime-keymap` file, to see where the problem come from. That's why I thought  the file was corrupted (sublime-package is a binary file, while sublime-keymap is a text file)